# Custom Error pages in MVC ASP NET for all errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, custom-error-pages

i want in my app to have custom error pages for 401, 404 etc error codes.

I try this but doesn't work?
In Web.config

```
<customErrors mode="Off" /> //Under system.web

<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace" >//Under system.webServer
  <clear />
  <remove statusCode="401"/>
  <error statusCode="401" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/Unauthorized" />
  <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/NotFound" />
  <error statusCode="500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error" />
</httpErrors>
```

I have create also Error controller and Unauthorized views.

How can this work?

Answer (score 2):

Example:

**web.config:**

in `system.web` add

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"  defaultRedirect="~/error">//RemoteOnly means that on local network you will see real errors
  <error statusCode="401" path="~/Error/Unauthorized" />
  <error statusCode="404" path="~/Error/NotFound" />
  <error statusCode="500" path="~/Error" />
</customErrors>
```

in `system.webServer` add

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
```

**Controller:**
your controller something like

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View("Error");
    }
    public ViewResult NotFound()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 404;
        return View("NotFound");
    }
}
```

**View:**
 and your view something like

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo
@{
    Layout = "_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Error";
}
<div class="list-header clearfix">
    <span>Error</span>
</div>
<div class="list-sfs-holder">
    <div class="alert alert-error">
        An unexpected error has occurred. Please contact the system administrator.
    </div>
    @if (Model != null && HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled)
    {
        <div>
            <p>
                <b>Exception:</b> @Model.Exception.Message<br />
                <b>Controller:</b> @Model.ControllerName<br />
                <b>Action:</b> @Model.ActionName
            </p>          
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Hopefully it's help for you.